# Installing Ubuntu - Boot Manager Troubles

Tags: ubuntu, installation, bios

## Specs - Acer Aspire - Intel Based System - UEFI Firmware

I'm trying to install Linux Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I had the issue of my Boot Manager not finding other bootable devices (my external HD, and dvd both with the ISO file). After switching UEFI to the BIOS Legacy boot option I was able to find both my external and the cd/dvd. When choosing the cd/dvd option it took me to the boot screen and said "No bootable devices found - Check Cables - Insert CD and Press Any Key." After choosing my external to boot from it takes me to a grey screen with a flashing underscore ( _ ). Looking at the external, its' light is flashing like it's doing something but after 5 minutes nothing happened. Is it possible my ISO (which was downloaded from ubuntu.com) is the problem? Do I need to be more patient with the flashing underscore? Any ideas/speculation is appreciated. Thanks, Alex

Comment: Ive also turned off 'Secure' and 'Fast' boot and re-prioritized the boot order so Windows Boot is the lowest priority

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it you can check this link which gives more steps to resolve it let me know if it doesnt helps